# Set the constraint to start with 0 then 9 only and contain 11 digits?

Tags: sql, sql-server, constraints

I am currently creating a database project wherein it only accepts a valid phone number that starts with "09" then the rest are any numbers, although it should be limited to only 11 numbers including 09. With my code below, it accepnt only 11 numbers but even when I tried numbers 63256115426 like that it can still be accepted.

```
([ContactNo]>=(0) AND [ContactNo]<=(9999999999.))
```

Comment: What's the data type of the column `ContactNo`?

Comment: Super niave solution would be to check ([ContactNo]>=(09000000000) instead of 0

Comment: `PhoneNumber LIKE '09[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'`?

Comment: Despite their names, phone numbers should not be stored as numbers, but as a string data type. Otherwise numbers with leading zero's would have them stripped, and that means that they are no longer a valid phone number. This is true for several "things" that use numbers as identifiers too. Such as Zip Codes, and Card and Account numbers, and Bank Sort Codes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first issue you've out there is that you're using the wrong datatype for phone numbers, thus you need to use a proper  on which is in your case `CHAR(11)/VARCHAR(11)`.

Then you need to create the [constraint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/unique-constraints-and-check-constraints?view=sql-server-ver15) as the following:

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable (
  ContactNo varchar(255)
  CONSTRAINT CK_ContactNo2 
  CHECK (ContactNo LIKE '09[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]')                 
); 



INSERT INTO MyTable(ContactNo) VALUES ('11111') -- Fail
INSERT INTO MyTable(ContactNo) VALUES ('09123456789')-- Succeed
```

and don't forgot to drop the previous one that if you're no re-creating your table.

Comment: What's the need of the first check if we already have it? Also you just copy/past my comment, if you didn't then you won't add a constraint to check 11 chars and another requires 13. Thus any attempt to insert data into table will fail

Comment: It seems like the OP wants `09[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]` (11 in total). Add that at least as a comment.

Answer (score 2):

You need to have your phone contact in a CHAR(11) and not in any numeric datatype, because the first 0 will be mathematically removed.
As I see, your constraint matche a numerical datatype and not a char string.
With the proper datatype, the constraints give by Sandra Guilep Zouaoui Zandeh is the right one.
You must take a numerical datatype for any columsn only if you need to compute the data. As far as I remenber I have never seen any calculus over phone numbers...